# express.js - serve different pages based on ip

Tags: node.js, express, http

I'm developing a NodeJS server that runs on a Raspberry PI. The Pi is attached to a screen and shows a website in kiosk mode. Users that see that screen can also connect to the server, but should be given a different page. I want both sites to run on the root (`http://localhost/` and `http://serverIP/`), but serve different pages.

The server should see if the localhost is making a request or if any other device is making the request and serve the appropriate page.

Currently I can reach the same page on both localhost and a remote device and also see if it is done by the localhost or the remote. But when I try to redirect the remote IPs, they get stuck in a redirect loop.

```
app.use('/', function(request, response, next) {
    let clientIP = getClientIP(request);
    console.log('client IP: ', clientIP);
    if (clientIP == '::1' || clientIP == '::ffff:127.0.0.1') {
        // if localhost request go to next middleware to direct it to the public/index.html
        next();
    } else {
        // if remote device request return the mobile page in public/mobilepage/mobile.html
        response.redirect('/mobilepage'); //This gets stuck in a loop because when redirected app.use() gets called again with the redirected request and sees it is not localhost and will redirect again. What should I better do here?
    }
}, express.static('public'));

function getClientIP(request){
    return request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;
}
```

My project folder looks like this

```
ProjectFolder/
| - server.js                //the node server
| - public/                  //the folder with the website
|   | - index.html           //the localhost main website
|   | - assets/              //folder with all the css and js for the localhost website
|   | - mobilepage/          //folder with the page for the remote devices
|   |   | - mobile.html      //the page for the remote devices
|   |   | - mobileStyle.css  //the style for the remote devices page
|   |   | - mobileScript.js  //the script for the remote devices page
|   | - sites/               //folder with all other sites for the localhost website 
|
| - ...                      //other files like node_modules etc. that are not important to the question
```

I hope I explained my situation well enough. If something is unclear please let me know, I would love to get some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can install a package called as [express-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ip)

   ```
    const express = require('express');
     const app = express();
     const expressip = require('express-ip');
     app.use(expressip().getIpInfoMiddleware);

     app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.send(req.ipInfo);
        });
   ```

   *Note* in app.use use conditional logic based on the value of req.ipInfo and your objective.

Also, This won’t work if you are at localhost, since it needs to get the IP to do a lookup. So to test it, use ngrok to expose http://localhost:yourportvalue.

Comment: Thank you for your useful response. This seems to work well. But it leaves me with one last question and that is how to get the behavior back that `app.use(express.static('public'));` provides? I would like to have my `public/` directory as  relative  for all the imports of my stylesheets, images, scripts etc. (localhost:3000/assets/js/script.js). I would rather not make a `app.get()` for every file that I will need. Is that still possible or is that inherently not possible due to my desire of having two different pages as the root?

Comment: OK, I am sorry. I posted that comment too quickly. The answer was quite simple: `app.use('/assets', express.static('public/assets');`. Add that line for every other folder that needs to be exposed. Thank you for your answer Jatin Mehrotra!